# Optimizar if en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, condiciones

Se podría optimizar un if como este para que ocupe menos?

```
if(e === '+' || e === '-' || e === '*' || e === '/' )
```

Comment: Podrías usar `if(['+','-','*','/'].includes(e))`

Comment: Tu solución es lo suficientemente buena como para ser una respuesta, Jaime. Aunque sea breve, seguro que les resulta útil a otros usuarios. ;)

Comment: En realidad es una [*refactorizacion*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refactorizaci%C3%B3n) no una [*optimización*](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizaci%C3%B3n_(c%C3%B3mputo)). No confundir los términos, ya que no son intercambiables. Saludos

Comment: @Mauricio : Mientras el PO no aclare "ocupe menos" ¿qué? no podemos distinguirlo. ¿Cuál es el objetivo? ¿Menos código? ¿Menos memoria? ¿Menos comparaciones?.